# Is (*argv[2])[2] legal and does it point to the first character of the pointer argv[2]?

Tags: c

I was trying to make a program that receives input from the command line. My program is supposed to only receive strings of 2 characters (that represent cards) and store the first character in a variable that will represent the value of the card and store the second character in another variable that will represent the suit of the card. Thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at how the operators bind in `(*argv[2])[2]`.

Starting from `argv`, between `*` and `[2]` the latter has higher precedence. So `*` is applied to `argv[2]`, a pointer to the third argument (second if you don't count `argv[0]` as an argument). `argv[2]` is a pointer to `char`, so applying `*` yields the pointed-to character (the first character of the third argument).

After that you're applying `[2]` to a `char`, which is a constraint violation. One of the operands of `[]` must have pointer type and the other must have integral type.

Now, I don't know what you mean by "the first character of the pointer". But if you want the first character of the string pointed to by `argv[2]`, you can get that as `*argv[2]` or `argv[2][0]`.

Comment: And if I want the second character of argv[2] do I type argv[2][1] then?

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice day : D